# ASP.net MVC Routing question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

In my ASP.Net MVC app, I have the following controllers

- HomeController
- ExController

ExController has this method that takes string parameters:

```
public ActionResult Index(String id){....
```

With parameters, the page opens successfully as: mysite.com/Ex/Index/my-string-value

but I want it to take parameters as: mysite.com/Ex/my-string-value

Here are my routing entries:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Post",
            "{controller}/{action}/{postId}",
            new { controller = "Ex", action = "Index", postId="" }
            );
```

What I need to do to send get parameters to ExController by typing mysite.com/Ex/GetParameter instead of mysite.com/Ex/Index/GetParameter. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to define the Ex-route **before** the default route, otherwise the default will catch all.
Second you can simply do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Post",
            "Ex/{postId}",
            new { controller = "Ex", action = "Index", postId="" }
            );
```

That will enable you to do `www.mysite.com/Ex/GetParameter`

You also need to change you Index action on you ExController to:

```
public ActionResult Index(String postId){....
```

to get the Modelbinder to bind postId correctly.

That will then in turn call the action Index passing `GetParameter` as the postId

Hope this helps!